# Dynamic Rule Engine

Tags: c#, expression-trees, rule-engine

I am trying to build a rule engine in c# in which users define rules in JSON format and I compile it to `C#` code at runtime. I am following this article

http://coding-time.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-implement-rule-engine-in-c.html

Everything is working fine, but this rule engine seems to work only for AND conditions. I am not able to find any way to put OR condition.

Here is my code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public class ProductFamily
    {
        public int MotorHP
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public String StationType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    static Expression BuildExpr<T>(Rule r, ParameterExpression param)
    {
        var left = MemberExpression.Property(param, r.MemberName);
        var tProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(r.MemberName).PropertyType;
        ExpressionType tBinary;
        // is the operator a known .NET operator?
        if (ExpressionType.TryParse(r.Operator, out tBinary))
        {
            var right = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(r.TargetValue, tProp));
            // use a binary operation, e.g. 'Equal' -> 'u.Age == 15'
            return Expression.MakeBinary(tBinary, left, right);
        }
        else
        {
            var method = tProp.GetMethod("Contains",new[] { typeof(string) });
            var tParam = method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
            var right = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(r.TargetValue, tParam));
            // use a method call, e.g. 'Contains' -> 'u.Tags.Contains(some_tag)'
            return Expression.Call(left, method, right);
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(@"TextFile1.txt");

        RulesManager ruleManagerObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RulesManager>(json);
        //List<Rule> rulesObj = new List<Rule>
        //{
        //    new Rule("MotorHP", "GreaterThan", "20"),
        //    new Rule("StationType", "Equal", "Horizontal Centrifugal")
        //};

        //RulesManager ruleObj = new RulesManager()
        //{
        //    rules = rulesObj,
        //    Message = "Test Failed!"

        //};

        var productFamily1 = new ProductFamily
        {
            MotorHP = 21,
            StationType = "Horizontal Cfugall"
        }

        ;
        var productFamily2 = new ProductFamily
        {
            MotorHP = 21,
        }

        ;
        var productFamily3 = new ProductFamily
        {
            MotorHP = 13,
        };

        //var rule = new Rule("MotorHP", "GreaterThan", "20");
        //Func<ProductFamily, bool> compiledRule = CompileRule<ProductFamily>(rule);

        //bool isMatch = compiledRule(productFamily1);
       

        // Compile all the rules once.
        var compiledRules = ruleManagerObj.rules.Select(r => CompileRule<ProductFamily>(r)).ToList();
        if (!compiledRules.Any(rule => rule(productFamily1)))
            Console.WriteLine(ruleManagerObj.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    public static Func<T, bool> CompileRule<T>(Rule r)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductFamily));
        Expression expr = BuildExpr<T>(r, param);
        // build a lambda function User->bool and compile it
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expr, param).Compile();
    }

    public class RulesManager
    {
        //Func<ProductFamily, Boolean> Matches { get; set; }

        public List<Rule> rules { get; set; }
        public Level Level { get; set; } // Level is an enum
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rule
    {
        public string MemberName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string Operator
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string TargetValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Rule(string MemberName, string Operator, string TargetValue)
        {
            this.MemberName = MemberName;
            this.Operator = Operator;
            this.TargetValue = TargetValue;
        }
    }

    public enum Level
    {
        Error = 1
    }
}
```

Json String:

```
{

  "rules": [
    {
      "MemberName": "MotorHP",
      "Operator": "GreaterThan",
      "TargetValue": "20"
    },
    {
      "MemberName": "StationType",
      "Operator": "Contains",
      "TargetValue": "Horizontal Centrifugal"
    }
  ],
  "Level": 1,
  "Message": "Test Failed!"
}
```

Is there any way I can add OR condition or a combination of conditions while evaluating expressions or rules.

Example:

```
(rule1 && rule2 && ... ruleN) && (rule1 || rule2 || ... ruleM)
```

Comment: Expression trees are not compiled to C# code at runtime. They are compiled to intermediate language (IL), which is what C# code also compiles to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Expression.AndAlso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso?view=net-5.0) and [`Expression.OrElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.orelse?view=net-5.0).

So for example an expression `(rule1 && rule2) && (rule3 || rule4 || rule5)` would be constructed with:

```cs
Expression.AndAlso(
    Expression.AndAlso(rule1, rule2),
    Expression.OrElse(Expression.OrElse(rule3, rule4), rule5)
);
```